# How do I rotate an image on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image-processing, uiimage, image-manipulation

How do I rotate an image in iPhone programming?

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917713/uiimage-rotation-custom-degrees

Comment: Might be a dupe, but depends on what the OP actually wants to do. Raju, what's the goal? Do you mean "get a copy of a UIImage that is rotated?" Or perhaps "display an image rotated?" Or perhaps "animate an image rotation?" This is a very vague questions.

Comment: This might also be similar to what he's asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839296/how-can-i-rotate-a-uiimageview-with-respect-to-any-point-other-than-its-center

Answer (score 2):

A great rotation and image UIImage category by Allen Brunson can be found here:
http://www.platinumball.net/blog/2010/01/31/iphone-uiimage-rotation-and-scaling/

Answer (score 1):

```
image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.142);
```

rotates it 180 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate a view using a CCGAffineTransform.  You can create a rotation matrix by specifying the degrees in radians you want to rotate, then setting the rotation matrix to be the .transform property of your view.

Answer (score 0):

```
//If someone needs in swift 3 



    func rotateImageClockWise(theImage: UIImage,imageView:UIImageView) -> UIImage {

        var orient: UIImageOrientation!
        let imgOrientation = theImage.imageOrientation


        UIView.transition(with: imageView, duration: 0.2, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {() -> Void in

            switch imgOrientation {

            case .left:
                orient = .up

            case .right:
                orient = .down

            case .up:
                orient = .right

            case .down:
                orient = .left

            case .upMirrored:
                orient = .rightMirrored

            case .downMirrored:
                orient = .leftMirrored

            case .leftMirrored:
                orient = .upMirrored

            case .rightMirrored:
                orient = .downMirrored
            }


        }, completion: { _ in })

        let rotatedImage = UIImage(cgImage: theImage.cgImage!, scale: 1.0, orientation: orient)
        return rotatedImage
    }
//Just call the method like this :

rotateImageClockWise(theImage: UIImage,imageView:UIImageView)
```