# How to rotate an image in iOS using gyroData?

Tags: ios5

Using coreMotion, I calculated the gyroData. Now I want to rotate an image according to the iPhone orientation. Please tell me how can I rotate the image?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I rotate an image on the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955635/how-do-i-rotate-an-image-on-the-iphone)

Comment: IN this sample code he is rotating the image to 90deg but my requirements is like, i have to rotate the image according to the device orientation.

Comment: you say you have the gyro data. The answer is in that question: rotate with a transform including your rotation in radians.