# Rotating image on iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, rotation, gesture

How to rotate the image with 2 finger gesture. Would be great if you could provide a link for a simple example.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108768/ios-pinch-scale-and-two-finger-rotate-at-same-time

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955635/how-do-i-rotate-an-image-on-the-iphone

Comment: Thanks for valuable inputs people.