# How to place and rotate UIImageView that is larger than screen active area?

Tags: iphone, animation, uikit, uiimageview, rotation

I have an image that represents sun rays and I need to make rotate those sun rays on iphone 4 screen. The very intuitive solution that comes to my head is to have quite large image, put it in UIImageView, set its anchor point and then use CA animation ([animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839296/how-can-i-rotate-a-uiimageview-with-respect-to-any-point-other-than-its-center)). I'm designing my UI with interface builder and the problem is I'm unable to put large image that is larger than active screen (root view) size to UIImageView because is just crops it. Any thoughts and solutions?

Comment: If you don't use Interface Builder, it's pretty straightforward.  Is IB changing the bounds of your UIImageView to the displayed area?

Comment: Hm, I don't know :) I'm putting image to UIImageView and what I see is croped image in the active area. Because my image is very large, I would like to move it to some x =-500 px and y =-500 px from the top left corner (0, 0). I'm not very familiar with CA animation :( Maybe you have working solution or even simple example how to implement that from code? Could you post it to an answer, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this (in code, not in IB):

```
UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"starburst.png"]];
img.center = CGPointMake (0, 0);
[self.view addSubview:img];
```

Then, to animate it, maybe something like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
img.alpha = 0.0f;
[img release];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

(Don't forget to release the img when you're done using it -- I did it above as an example, but you could move the release anywhere you needed)

Comment: Right now I have it doing an alpha fade, but this could just as easily be a move (by moving the center point, for example), a resize (by changing the frame), or a rotation/transformation...